# What does C++ Graph mean in Intel Concurrent Collections?

Tags: c++, concurrency, intel

I am reading the [user guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pre-release-license-agreement-for-intel-concurrent-collections-for-cc-accept-end-user-license-agreement-and-download/) that came with Intel concurrent collections, and I don't understand what they mean by the following sentence **[Page 4 Section 1.1]**:

> You define an Intel Concurrent Collections for C++ graph which specifies the following:

Anybody know what do they mean by `C++ Graph`?

Comment: The graph component is described a few pages later.  Keep reading.

Comment: Do you mean section 1.2 (or even later than that)? I am reading through it right now, and I understand the very high level concept they are trying to make me understand, but again, they use the words `... to represent an Intel Concurrent Collections for C++ Graph`. What the heck is a C++ graph!? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not talking about a **C++** graph - they're talking about an **Intel Concurrent Collections for C++** graph.

The graph that's described here is not some general C++ concept, it's completely specific to this framework, and created as described in detail in the document, starting with the overview in Section 1.1.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. I started digging through other documents and FAQs, which clear it up further:

1) [CnC FAQ][1]
2) Primes project which comments `context class (also known as graph)`

[1]: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-concurrent-collections-for-cc/#FAQ